# FFmpeg scale video to desire size

Tags: video, ffmpeg, scale

I have an video with this resolution: 1920x1080,

I want to scale it to 480x852, like this video:

https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/d7b76fe78c9ad72016b98dcda320a6ca/5BA532D8/t50.16885-16/10000000_232772710752607_772643665699930112_n.mp4

but it seems it's not working correctly.

here is my command:

```
-i input.mp4 -vf scale=480x852,setdar=1:009 -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -profile:v main -crf 18 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Where do I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
-vf scale=480:-1,pad=480:852:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setdar=1
```